# How to compute the % of network computing power the attacker hold?

Tags: tangle, security, double-spending, white-paper

It is known generally that Tangle is susceptible to 34% attack(of total computing power) that gives a 100% successful attack. The example given on page 19 of white paper says that an upper limit to the probability of a successful attack is 29% given the attacker computing power μ = 2 and honest transaction rate λ = 3. How do we compute the % of network computing power the attacker hold in this example? Do we need to convert first, μ into λ_a which is the transactions issuing rate by the attacker?